# How to store input from keyboard into variable?

Tags: autohotkey

I am currently using Random function in Autohotkey to generate random and save into variable rand but if user presses R.

my question is below this code

```
    R::
    Random, rand, 1, 3
    Msgbox, %rand%

if (rand = "1")
{
    ;SAM()
}
else if (rand = "2")
{
    ;AAJ()
}
else if (rand = "3")
{
    ;HEAD()
}
else
{
    ;Msgbox, else
}
```

I also want to add code where if user presses 1 it will, may if I can add OR expression in if statement such as

```
if (rand = "1" || keyboardinput = "1" )
{
    ;SAM()
}
```

Comment: So now R or C? I see that's K&R, but the R does not stand for what you think it stands for...

Comment: Sorry I don't get you?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the same approach u used with your code for generating random numbers.

```
1::
    if( rand == 1)
    {
        tooltip, hello
    }
return
```

You are also missing a return at the end of the first part of your code, unless you want the script to start executing things it shouldn't.

Comment: what if user presses 11 or 12 or 2 digit number?

Comment: so i have 2 option for user either they can enter input, or they can press R to generate input for them.

Comment: There is no 11 or 12 key on the keyboard.<- think about it, if you wan't to detect a 2 digit number you're goint to have to code it. You should read [this](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm), how to make [combinations](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Features) and try some examples.

Comment: I already have It figured out for two combination but I can't figure out implementing  random function into it.